# Is there any conditional jackson json strategy?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, jackson, deserialization, geojson

I need to deserialize a [GeoJSON JSON object](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) with the Jackson library. In this json object there are places where this applies:
If there is

```
"type" : "name"
```

than the following json object is of one type. Lets say, for example:

```
"properties": {
   "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
}
```

On the other hand, if there is

```
"type": "link"
```

than the following json object is of another type. Lets say, for example:

```
"properties": {  
   "href": "http://example.com/crs/42",  
   "type": "proj4"  
}
```

Now I have a PropertiesPOJO which contains:

```
private String name;  
private String href;
private String type;
```

**The current solution demands checking the object's type so we know which parts of the PropertiesPOJO we want to consider.** This is not a good practice. I would rather do this with a custom deserializer which will deserialize directly to NamePropertiesPOJO or LinkPropertiesPOJO. One idea that I had is to place

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=PropertiesDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("properties")
NamePropertiesPOJO namePropertiesPOJO = null;

@JsonDeserialize(using=PropertiesDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("properties")
LinkPropertiesPOJO linkPropertiesPOJO = null;
```

But I get a

> JsonMappingException happened:Multiple
>   fields representing property
>   "properties":

**So, is there any other way I can do this more OO using jackson's annotations?**

Kind Regards,
Despot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as "External type id", and while it is not yet supported by Jackson (unlike type identifiers that would be embedded in Object; in this case, as one additional property), it is something for which support should be added in future, as per [JACKSON-453](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-453). It won't make it in 1.8, but hopefully for version after that.
GeoJSON is a commonly recurring use case for this -- I wish they had chosen more common mechanism, but due to popularity of format this is a high-priority thing to support.

Comment: Thanks for the info StaxMan! This is good to know. I can also see one more shortcoming of Jackson (although it is a pretty good library). It cannot figure out how to parse a JSON object when you provide a List.class. I know this isn't jackson's job to foresee, but this was a real scenario (I am expecting a JSON Array), but sometimes when the request is bad or if the server that we request isn't responding we get a JSON Object instead of JSON Array. So, I had to override the protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) to check for '{'. off topic but nice to know

Comment: Hmmh. I am not sure I understand the problem... if you wanted to specify contents of the array (which needs type parameters), that can be done using TypeReference (like, new TypeReference<List<Bean>>() { }). Maybe you could explain the problem at jackson user list?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it via

```
class Pojo {
    Map<String,String> properties;
    ...
}
```

And then just read the stuff from the map.

Also when you just have the POJO that you showed without annotations, Jackson should also 
be able to fill in the right variables by itself. And in the setters you could set a flag it this is type 1 or type 2, so you can then do `if (pojo.isType1())`

Comment: The first part that you showed here is achieved by @JsonAnySetter which is even worse than my design - it will populate the properties variable with all the json parameters available... The second approach that you propose, is not good since it interferes with the POJO definition. POJO should only have simple setters and getters. And additionally I really don't need this, since I can do a if (type.equals("name") or if (type.equals("link"), and have the same functionality. The trick is to have the jackson deserializer do this for us! Nice try though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simple answer would be, there is no conditional deserialization jackson json strategy.

Cheers,
Despot
P.S.: If someone gives me a solution to the problem (other than "no") I would happily transfer the answer check to his answer!